# Hide y-axis without hiding grid in chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I would like to show horizontal gridlines without showing the y-Axis. Is it possible?

If I set:

```
y: {
    display: false,
    grid: {
        display: true
    }
}
```

gridlines are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom tick callback that just returns an empty string:

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    callback: function(value, index, ticks) {
                        return '';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable ticks and drawTicks in your grid:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'line',
data: data,
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            grid: {
              drawTicks: false
            },
            ticks: {
              display: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});